# PHP: Why the 'abs' function returns a wrong number if it begins with zero?

Tags: php, absolute, octal

The code "abs(070000)" returns 28672, but the code "abs(70000)" returns 70000.

Did the zero at the beginning means that the number is interpreted as hex?

Thank you!

Comment: "... number is interpreted as hex?" Nope, octal (base 8), cf. @DuoSRX's answer.

Comment: @Paulocoghi `abs(7000000)` will not return `70000`. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Numbers beginning by zero are interpreted as octal.

See [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Comment: If I compare two numbers, one in decimal and the other in octal, does the comparison will be done correctly?

Comment: Like "if(a < b)", but a is octal and b is decimal.

Comment: Ok ok... now I understand. This comparison will be done the wrong way, because the number has changed its base.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm removing the beginning's zeros with the function 'ltrim($string_of_numbers,"0")'. [SOLVED]